# disappearing answer

Tags: support

I answered a question, and now I see the question has reappeared without my answer; whereas the answer I provided is not showing up on my activity log.  It seems unlikely I would not have posted it after taking the trouble to write all that Latex.

What could have happened.  Should I answer the new question again?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: At the end of  [your list of answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/89003/betty-mock?tab=answers) there should be a link `deleted recent answers`. Check if your answer is there.

Comment: The original question seems to have reappeared with my answer.  Thanks for your suggestions.